# Do we need RXJS combineLatest with ActivateRouted.pathFromRoot?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

The Angular Material Documentation application retrieves route parameters from lazy loaded route modules like this:

https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-category-list/component-category-list.ts

```
// Combine params from all of the path into a single object.
    this.params = combineLatest(
        this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params), Object.assign);
```

It  seems like we don't really need `combineLatest` for this?

The `_route` is constructor injected and IIUC once the component has the reference to it the `pathFromRoot` array of `ActivateRoute` instance cannot change?

Since that's the case we don't need `combineLatest`?

So it seems like we could do something like this instead:

```
const paramArr = this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)

this.params = of(Object.assign(paramArr))
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In

```ts
const paramArr = this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)
```

`pathFromRoute` and therefore `route` won't change. But `route.params` is an Observable and this Observable can emit new values over time. To get notified when one of those Observables emits a new value you have to subscribe to all of those Observables. That's why `combineLatest` is used.

---

```ts
this.params = of(Object.assign(paramArr))
```

Isn't really helpful. It creates an Observable that emits an array of Observables so you'd have to flatten this Observable in another step. When you use `combineLatest` you won't need this extra step.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like we don't really need combineLatest for this?

I'd say it is needed, but it also depends on what you'd want to achieve.

For instance, with this approach:

```js
const paramArr = this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)

this.params = of(Object.assign(paramArr))
```

You'd get the params from the `ActivatedRoute` root to the current `ActivatedRoute` child **only once**. Meaning that if the `params` of a route gets updated(e.g first you navigate to `/1`, then to `/2`), you'd only get `1`.
Also, I'm not sure this would work as expected, since `paramsArr` will be an array of observables(`ActivatedRoute.params` is a `BehaviorSubject` AFAIK).

Whereas if you use this approach:

```js
this.params = combineLatest(
        this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params), Object.assign);
```

You will be notified of all the `params` updates that occur in the `ActivatedRoute` tree, not only once, but every time.

I've elaborated on how `ActivatedRoute` works(among other things) in [this article](https://andreigatej.dev/blog/angular-router-urlree).